# Read File byte for byte and parse to int

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have to read data from an file. This data was written by an server byte-wise into the file. The file has an fix structure, now I want to read the Information in it with JS.

I have found http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ and copied it down to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/egLof4ph/

```
function readBlob(opt_startByte, opt_stopByte) {

    var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
    if (!files.length) {
        alert('Please select a file!');
        return;
    }

    var file = files[0];
    var start = parseInt(opt_startByte) || 0;
    var stop = parseInt(opt_stopByte) || file.size - 1;

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
            document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent = evt.target.result;
            document.getElementById('byte_range').textContent = ['Read bytes: ', start + 1, ' - ', stop + 1,
                ' of ', file.size, ' byte file'].join('');
        }
    };

    var blob = file.slice(start, stop);

var a = reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);

}

document.querySelector('.readBytesButtons').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
        var startByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-startbyte');
        var endByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-endbyte');
        readBlob(startByte, endByte);
    }
}, false);
```

I knew that the first 7 Bytes are crap and can throw them away. The next 68Bytes belong together and every value is 4bytes big. After the 68Bytes again 68 usable bytes come (that 68bytes are "timeslots").

My Question:
When I am using that Code I get many signs (A, Q, &&&, special chars,..), but the data are in reality longs. How can I parse them into Numbers? According to the Filereader API readAsBinarsString() returns raw binary data. And how to correctly parse the whole File?

So, the original File looks like this:

```
    <7B>Metadata</7B><4B>long value</4B>....17times for each timeslot      <4B>long value</4B>....17times again.... and this util the end of the file.
```

When I am using the above Code I get output like: �&�&WK��

Furthermore I have found: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays (since FileReader provides an method which returns an ArrayBuffer), so I guess I should use readAsArrayBuffer(), but how to use it to get to my data?

Comment: do you have an example of the file you want to parse?

Comment: Sadly not, I only have an File where I can see how the original data look like. I update this in my Startingpost.

Comment: Do you realy need this? Why not read/process the file at the server and return the Int that you need?

Answer (score 0):

You really need binary ?

Note that readAsBinaryString method is now deprecated as per the 12 July 2012 Working Draft from the W3C.

```
function readBlob(opt_startByte, opt_stopByte) {

    var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
    if (!files.length) {
      alert('Please select a file!');
      return;
    }

    var file = files[0];
    var start = parseInt(opt_startByte) || 0;
    var stop = parseInt(opt_stopByte) || file.size - 1;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function (evt) {

      if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
        var a = new Uint8Array(evt.target.result)
        var binary = ""
        for (var i =0; i <= a.length; i++) {
          binary += Number(a[i]).toString(2)
        }
        document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent = binary;
        document.getElementById('byte_range').textContent = ['Read bytes: ', start + 1, ' - ', stop + 1,
          ' of ', file.size, ' byte file'].join('');
      }
    };;


    var blob = file.slice(start, stop);
    var a = reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob)
  }

  document.querySelector('.readBytesButtons').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
      var startByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-startbyte');
      var endByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-endbyte');
      readBlob(startByte, endByte);
    }
  }, false);
```

Comment: I am not allowed to touch the Encoding, so yes, can´t change that it is binary. Yeah I relized yesterday that the readAs... does return nothing, unlike what I thought, I didn´t saw the attribute result.   Is there any difference if I use a Typed Array or an DataView?